# How to get android tab text in one language always

Tags: android, tabs

My app has 3 languages and for one of my requirement I need to get tab text in english whatever be the language of my app. Is there any way to do so without using if cases

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site nor search engine replacement. We can help, but it's **your** job to work on this in first place. [Put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)first, then ask with a clear explanation and [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if applicable. Also read [How to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to [reward helpful answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) and general [StackOverflow Do and Don't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937)s.

Comment: Why without if cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could just have English string for the tab text in your resources regardless the `values-*` you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution, provide a static string for tabs, if you look at 'setupViewPager' method in the example code below, you find that tabs are named as "ONE","TWO","THREE".

(source: https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```